# Stored procedure add hyperlink to column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have modified my `SELECT` statement in a stored procedure so that its column "Ticket" contain hyperlink to some javascript action but it gives me error saying `Invalid Column Name Ticket`

```
Set @SQL = 'Select ''<a href=' + CHAR(39) + 'javascript:editTicketByIDAction(' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + ')' + CHAR(39) + '>' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + '</a>'' Ticket,VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket],Comments From dbo.VendorTickets Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() And IsNull(NotifyOn,0)<>0 '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(250)='Select ''<a href="javascript:editTicketByIDAction('' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + '')">'' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + ''</a>'', Ticket,[Vendor Ticket],Comments From dbo.VendorTickets Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() And IsNull(NotifyOn,0)<>0  '
```